# What do you call subsets of $G$-sets whose elements are permuted under some action $G$?

Tags: group-theory, permutations

Given any group $G$ acting on any set $X$ via some left or right action $\varphi:G\times X\to X$ is there a name for subsets $Y\subseteq X$ with the property that for any $g\in G$ wge have $\{\varphi(g,y):y\in Y\}=Y$?

So that intuitively any element of $G$ acts on the elements of $Y$ by permuting them.

Comment: They are called 
"$G$-invariant" or "$\varphi$-invariant"

Comment: @EthanBolker Are those names equivalent? I.e. is it possible for some set to be invariant under a particular group action of $G$ but not others? In which case specifying the particular action ($\varphi$ in this case) would be necessary.

Comment: Indeed. It's the action that's invariant. If there's only one in the current context you need not specify it. You should be able to think of actions with different invariant sets.

Comment: Sorry to be pedantic, so you are saying yes one has to specify the group action if its not known but the group $G$ is. As simply specifying $G$ would not be enough. Correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"G-invariant" is mentioned in the comments above, though technically you should say "G-invariant subset" since other things than subsets (e.g., properties) can also be G-invariant.  The other, even simpler, name is "a union of orbits".

Comment: Wait, can every invarient subset be written as a union of orbits?

Comment: Suppose it isn't a union of orbits.  Since the orbits partition $X$, there is some orbit $Z$ with $Z\cap Y$ different from both $\emptyset$ and $Z$.  Then there is some $z\in Z\cap Y$ and $g\in G$ with $zg \in Z\setminus Y$ (or the converse, but then replace $z$ with $zg$ an $g$ with $g^{-1}$ to get the statement).  Thus if $Y$ is not a union of orbits it is not a $G$-invariant subset.